# How to get final types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

If I have the following two types in `type.ts`:

```
type bar = {
  firstname: string;
};

type foo = {
  lastname: string;
};

// then I merge two types like `type final = A & B`
type final = A & B;
```

there is any functional way like `cli type.ts` to generate final type result `type-result.ts`.

```
type final = {
  firstname: string
  lastname: string
}
```

Comment: What's `A` and `B` here?  What do you mean by "final"?  Do you want actual code generation or something that evaluates to `{firstname: string; lastname: string}` when you examine it with IntelliSense, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2EVYW)?

Comment: @jcalz What is the `extends infer T` syntax?

Comment: @jiangweixian This is a what jcalz means by "code generation": https://tsplay.dev/wX2ZVm (That example is hardcoded specifically for your question input.)

Comment: @jsejcksn it's [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).

Comment: @jcalz I know that part, but in your example, are you using the conditional (because it always evaluates to true?) simply as a way to create an alias `T` for `A & B`?

Comment: Pretty much; you could write `type Final = { [K in keyof (A & B)]: (A & B)[K] }` and repeat `A & B`; note that something like `type Final = Id<A & B>; type Id<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}` runs the risk of seeing `Id<A & B>` in IntelliSense/quickinfo in various places.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.