# Is there a way to stop a sub class from overriding a method in typescript?

Tags: typescript, class

I am looking to prevent a subclass from being able to override a method in a class in TypeScript. In other languages I would use `final` on the method to indicate that it cannot be overridden but that isn't a part of TypeScript/JavaScript so that isn't an option.

I am trying to implement a bunch of different types of sensors in a simulator, with one of the important things being that I am able to sample the sensors at one time and then retrieve the sampled value at another time.

Here is a simplified version of the code

```
interface Sensor<T> {
  sample(): void; // public method to tell sensor to sample
  read(): T; // public method to get the previously sampled value
}

abstract class AbstractSensor<T> implements Sensor<T> {
  private value: T

  constructor(arg1, arg2, etc,  initialValue: T = undefined){
    this.value = initialValue
  }

  sample(): void {
    this.value = this.sensorSpecficValue()
  }

  // Concrete sub classes would need to override this to return their specific sensor values
  protected abstract sensorSpecficValue(): T // Yes, this needs a new name

  read(): T {
    return this.value
  }
}
```

The above works fine (assuming I properly dumbed it down from the actual code) but it has the problem of allowing any concrete subclass of `AbstractClass` to simply override the `sample()` or `read()` methods, meaning that even if they properly implement the `sensorSpecficValue` method they could introduce a bug by changing the behavior of either of those methods.

Is there anything I can do here to indicate, at compile time, that those methods should not be overriden? Or an entirely different way to think about this code which would accomplish what I am after. My head is stuck on a solution like `final` so I could easily be missing an alternative solution.

Also I am fine with a solution that only works at compile time, I am aware that if a developer really wants to at runtime they could go in and change the `sample()` method in ways that I might not be able to catch at compile time, I'm OK with that.

Comment: Related, unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538647/how-to-get-final-types-in-typescript

Comment: *"Also I am fine with a solution that only works at compile time..."* If there isn't one, are you open to one that works at runtime?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah

Comment: No, there is no compile-time way to prohibit overriding a method; you're looking for [ms/TS#1534](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1534).  You could go to it and give it a  but realistically this feature doesn't exist.  You might consider refactoring away from abstract classes if you care about the compiler enforcing such constraints.  I would do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX7zOW) if I wanted to prevent such things from happening; even if the implementing class has a `read()` or `sample()` method it won't interfere.

Comment: Let me know if you want an answer like that.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, someone better at TypeScript than I will come along and provide a compile-time solution.

Until/unless they do, here's a runtime solution, which is obviously very much second-best:

```
// A couple of utility functions:

function freezeDataProperty(obj, propName) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, propName, {
    value: obj[propName],
  }); // `writable`, `configurable`, and `enumerable` all default to `false`
}
function forceNoOverride(instance, cls, methodName) {
  if (instance[methodName] !== cls.prototype[methodName]) {
    throw new Error(`Subclasses may not override the ${cls.name} '${methodName}' method`);
  }
  freezeDataProperty(instance, methodName);
}

// Using them:

abstract class AbstractSensor<T> implements Sensor<T> {
  private value: T

  constructor(arg1, arg2, etc,  initialValue: T = undefined){
    this.value = initialValue
    // Detect overrides and throw, and then prevent overrides on the instance
    forceNoOverride(this, AbstractSensor, "sample");
    forceNoOverride(this, AbstractSensor, "read");
  }

  sample(): void {
    this.value = this.sensorSpecficValue()
  }

  // Concrete sub classes would need to override this to return their specific sensor values
  protected abstract sensorSpecficValue(): T // Yes, this needs a new name

  read(): T {
    return this.value
  }
}
// Prevent replacement on the `AbstractSensor.prototype`
freezeDataProperty(AbstractSensor.prototype, "sample");
freezeDataProperty(AbstractSensor.prototype, "read");
```

It's probably not perfect, but if there's a way past it, someone would have to be making a serious effort to find it.

Answer (score 0):

for compile-time check, try:

```js
declare const _: unique symbol;
type NoOverride = { [_]: typeof _; }

class A {
  baz: string & NoOverride = '' as any;

  // Note - `ReturnValue & NoOverride`
  foo(): { a: string } & NoOverride {
    return { a: '' } as any;
  }

  // if this function return nothing, use `NoOverride` only
  bar(): NoOverride {
    console.log(0);

    return null!;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  // @ts-expect-error - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NoOverride'.
  baz = '';

  // @ts-expect-error - Property '[_]' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type 'NoOverride'.
  foo() {
    return { a: '' };
  }

  // @ts-expect-error - Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'NoOverride'.
  bar() {
  }
}
```